# Yammer JS SDK AutoComplete returning CORS error

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, sdk, yammer

I've recently started facing CORS error when I make autocomplete requests. I made sure both api endpoint and JS Origins are valid as specifies in the Specification, but I still getting this issue.

This is the code snippet i'm currently using for autocomplete request.

```
            yam.platform.request({
                    url: "autocomplete/ranked", 
                    method: "GET",
                    data: {
                      "models":"user:15",
                      "prefix": val        
                    },
                    success: function (response) {
                        if (response.user){
                            callback(users); 
                        };                       
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                      console.error(error);
                }
            });
```

The same logic used to work perfectly well even couple weeks of before, i'm not sure what broke it.

Can anyone help me resolve this issue.

Regards.

Comment: There is a bug with the autocomplete endpoint. It should be fixed soon. (I work at Yammer).

Comment: I was eventually able to get it working using the old api endpoint https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/autocomplete/ranked .